# Can we access or run kube-bench through rest api/curl?

Tags: rest, curl, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am working on container security using Kube-bench. I need to check cluster security through rest API or curl. I have done it using CLI but now I need to do this using curl

Answer (score 0):

Anything you can do via `kubectl` is possible with the API.

API usage docs are [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/) and then full reference docs are [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20). For example, [creating a deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#-strong-write-operations-deployment-v1-apps-strong-)

You can also see the APIs being called with kubectl by setting the [verbosity level](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-output-verbosity-and-debugging) : `--v=7` would show request headers and endpoints being called.